# Are non-zero prime ideals maximal in the ring of all algebraic integers?

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

> In the ring of all algebraic integers (i.e. the integral closure of the integers in the complex numbers), can we say that non-zero prime ideals are maximal?

It's very hard to find a counter example, it's difficult to find a prime ideal to begin with.

Answer (score 5):

That is (almost) correct. Actually by the *going-up* and *going-down theorems*,  for any integrally closed domain $A$ and any extension $L$ of its field of fractions, the integral closure $A'$ of $A$ in $L$ satisfies 
$$\dim A=\dim A'.$$
($\dim$ denotes the Krull dimension).

In the present case you apply this result to $\mathbf Z$ which has dimension $1$: any ring of algebraic integers also has dimension $1$, i.e. any *non-zero* prime ideal is maximal.

Comment: Looks to me as if OP is asking about the ring of *all* algebraic integers. This is not noetherian.

Comment: @Lubin: You're right, I removed the last part of my answer, which was irrelevant.

Comment: I’m *really* weak in commutative algebra. The theorems in question don’t depend on noetherian hypothesis?

Comment: No. They're also known as *1st* and *2nd Cohen-Seidenberg*  theorems.

Comment: If  $A\subset B$ is an extension of rings with $B$ is integral over $A$, then $\dim A=\dim B$. This has nothing to do with going down nor with $A$ being integrally closed (nor even with with $A$ or $B$ being a domain).